# How to determine whether this language is regular?

Tags: regular-languages, decidability

I've encountered this question recently: Given $\Sigma=\{\sigma_1, \sigma_2, ..., \sigma_n\}$ and $n\ge 2$, determine whether the following language is regular or not:
$$
L_1=\{w\in\Sigma^*|for \ 1 \le i \le n, \ \#_{\sigma_i}(w) \ is \ even \iff i \ is \ even \}
$$
And I need to use the Myhill-Nerode theorem to solve it.
I tried constructing a finite automata that accepts this language but had some troubles with it. I'd really appreciate some help!

Comment: I think the condition should be "for all $1 \leq i \leq n$, $\#_{\sigma_i}(w)$ even $\iff$ $i$ even", right? Otherwise it would be the empty language. Edit: For the sake of readability, the $\sigma$ contains $i$ instead of 1 as subscript.

Comment: This problem can be solved without constructing an automaton, so where are your problems? Understanding the language, or understanding Myhill-Nerode?

Answer (score 2):

For $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \{0,1\}^n$, define $C_x = \{ w \in \Sigma^* \mid \forall i=1,\dots,n, \;\; \#_{\sigma_i}(w) \equiv x_i \pmod{2} \}$. Notice that the collection $\mathcal{C} = \{C_x \mid x \in \{0,1\}^n\}$ is a partition of $\Sigma^*$ and that $|C| = 2^n$.

Let $\rho \subseteq \Sigma^* \times \Sigma^*$ be the equivalence relation "having no distinguishing extension" (see the [Myhill-Nerode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) theorem for a definition of "distinguishing extension"). I claim that the quotient set of $\Sigma^*$ by $\rho$ is exactly $\mathcal{C}$. By the Myhill-Nerode theorem, this immediately implies that $L_1$ is regular since $\mathcal{C}$ is a finite set.

To see that the claim is true, let $w,w' \in C_x$ for some $x \in \{0,1\}^n$.
For any $z \in \Sigma^*$ and any $i=1,\dots,n$ we have that
$$
\#_{\sigma_i}(wz) \equiv x_i + \#_{\sigma_i}(z) \equiv x_i + \#_{\sigma_i}(z)  \equiv \#_{\sigma_i}(w'z) \pmod{2},$$

showing that either both $wz$ and $w'z$ belong to $L_1$ or neither does. This means that there exists no distinguishing extension for $w$ and $w'$, i.e., $w$ and  $w'$ lie in the same equivalence class.

Conversely, let $w \in C_x$ and $w' \in C_y$  for some $x,y \in \{0,1\}^n$ with $x \neq y$. Let $j$ be any index such that $x_j \neq y_j$. We construct a distinguishing extension $z$ for $w$ and $w'$ as follows:
$$
z= \sigma_1^{1-x_1}\,\sigma_2^{x_2}\,\sigma_3^{1-x_3}\,\sigma_4^{x_4}\,\dots
$$

By construction $wz \in L_1$. Moreover, $w'z \not\in L_1$ since we must have:
$$
\#_{\sigma_j}(wz) \equiv x_j + \#_{\sigma_j}(z) \not\equiv y_j + \#_{\sigma_j}(z) \equiv \#_{\sigma_j}(w'z) \pmod{2}.
$$
This shows that $w$ and $w'$ belong to different equivalence classes and concludes the proof.